# Simple PostgreSQL query in Play Framework + Slick 3.0.0 ProvenShape issue

Tags: playframework-2.5

I am playing with Play Framework, and I am now trying to access a PostgreSQL database with a simple table "users", defined as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
id  | first_name | last_name | email | password 
-c--+------------+-----------+-------+----------
AI  | text       | text      | text  | text
```

In Play, I have my User case class :

```
case class User(id: Int, mail: String, pwd: String, firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

I am working with the following imports:

```
import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver._
import slick.lifted.Tag
```

I can use my database with the following

```
@Inject
// Inject Database config provider lib
var dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider = _

val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[PostgresDriver]

import dbConfig.driver._
```

I am following the doc of Slick 3.0.0 which is on this adress: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#queries . To build my request I have first tried to do the following:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int,String,String,String,String)](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def mail = column[String]("email")
  def pwd = column[String]("password")
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
  def * = (id,mail,pwd,firstName,lastName)
}
```

And it was not a success: my IDE says that Expression doesn't conform to expected type ProvenShape, and `./activator compile` says that

```
[...] could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[Int]
```

I secondly tried to use the following link slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#mapped-tables and wrote this:

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def mail = column[String]("email")
  def pwd = column[String]("password")
  def firstName = column[String]("first_name")
  def lastName = column[String]("last_name")
  def * = (id, mail, pwd, firstName, lastName) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

But the IDE is unable to recognize the "<>" symbol, plus there is missing args in the unapply method...

Do you have any clues for me? I am lost right now...

Thanks!

[screenshot of intellij error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGbw1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research, I finally found the problem. To fix it, I have:

- Updated Slick to last version in build.sbt:

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
)`

- Import the api (and not only the driver...)

`import dbConfig.driver._      // THIS was the problem
import dbConfig.driver.api._   // .api._ is important...`

Now everything is OK.